# Comparing time complexity for making list to set in a for loop and x in list in a for loop

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm doing the *GenomicRangeQuery* exercise from [Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/genomic_range_query/). (I don't paste the question here, because it is a bit too long.)

This is my answer and it has passed the tests. And it shows the *Detected time complexity* is O(N + M).

```
def solution(S, P, Q):
    impacts_dic = {"A": 1, "C": 2, "G": 3, "T": 4}

    result = []
    for i in range(len(P)):
        if P[i] == Q[i]:
            result.append(impacts_dic[S[P[i]]])
            continue

        impact_list = S[P[i]:Q[i] + 1]

        if "A" in impact_list:
            result.append(impacts_dic["A"])
        elif "C" in impact_list:
            result.append(impacts_dic["C"])
        elif "G" in impact_list:
            result.append(impacts_dic["G"])
        else:
            result.append(impacts_dic["T"])

    return result
```

Example test:

```
S = "CAGCCTA"

P = [2, 5, 0]
Q = [4, 5, 6]
print(solution(S, P, Q))

print(solution('A', [0], [0]))
```

But I don't quite understand why the time complexity is **O(N + M)**?

The time complexity for "for loop" is *O(M)* and "x in s" for list is *O(len(impact_list))*, where len(impact_list) <= N. But why the time complexity is not *O(N * M)*?

I also don't understand how to calculate the time complexity for my first try answer.
Instead of `impact_list = S[P[i]:Q[i] + 1]` I wrote `impact_set = set(S[P[i]:Q[i] + 1])`, and the time complexity is *O(N * M)*. I think it is because the time complexity for make the list to set is *O(n)*, and n <= N.

Comparing these two, why the first one is plus M and N but the second one is multiply M and N?

Comment: Did the O(N \* M) result for your `impact_set` version come from the same person as O(N + M) for the original? The set version isn’t better, but it shouldn’t be worse (by more than a constant factor) either.

Comment: Are you just assuming that it’s O(N + M) because it passes the tests? That’s not the case. You have two similar O(N \* M) solutions, one of which is just fast enough to squeak under the time limit.

Comment: @Ry- It shows the *Detected time complexity* with the score when the code is submitted.

Comment: Well, it seems to be wrong :P It seems like this case shouldn’t be hard to distinguish under some straightforward strategies, but I don’t know what they’re doing behind the scenes. (Note that there is in general no program that can take in an algorithm and always give you its time complexity correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detected time is wrong, and your manual analysis is right. Both solutions are O(N * M).

The shape of the curve doesn’t become visible for a while, so some automated methods might make a mistake, especially when Python operations can have vastly different constant factors.

I plotted the output of this program that sets N = M:

```py
import timeit


def solution(S, P, Q):
    impacts_dic = {"A": 1, "C": 2, "G": 3, "T": 4}

    result = []
    for i in range(len(P)):
        if P[i] == Q[i]:
            result.append(impacts_dic[S[P[i]]])
            continue

        impact_list = S[P[i]:Q[i] + 1]

        if "A" in impact_list:
            result.append(impacts_dic["A"])
        elif "C" in impact_list:
            result.append(impacts_dic["C"])
        elif "G" in impact_list:
            result.append(impacts_dic["G"])
        else:
            result.append(impacts_dic["T"])

    return result


def measure(n, m):
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: solution("C" * n, [0] * m, [n - 1] * m), number=3)


for n in range(1, 100002, 1000):
    print(f"{n}\t{measure(n, n):f}")
```

and as you can see, it’s a parabola, not the straight line you’d expect for O(N + M):

[image: plot of time against input size]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really clear! I was so confused and you save my day. :)